# Migrating Cassandra Key Space

Tags: cassandra

I am migrating from CASSANDRA version 1.1.2 to 1.1.5. I have some Key Spaces specific to 1.1.2. After I migrate my application to 1.1.5 version I need to use my old key space  with current version. For that I simply took the backup of the old key space and pasted into the new version db->data folder. Then I tried to read Key Space using current version. But It does not work for me.. can any one give me solution to migrate the key spaces..

thanks in advance..

Comment: The keyspace already exists in the new version ? Did you stopped the cassandra server before you pasted the copy ?